# How to get the system default encoding in Python 2.x?

Tags: python-2.7, character-encoding

I tried `sys.getdefaultencoding()` but unfortunately that doesn't work. It returns `ascii` on my system which has the system locale set to ja_JP (i.e. the encoding should be Shift-JIS).

I'm trying to parse CJK text (on Windows). I need to read some text from keyboard, determine the system encoding, and convert it to utf8. I would often change my system locale between zh_CN (GBK encoding) and ja_JP (Shift-JIS encoding) so hard-coding the system encoding (encoding of keyboard-input text) is not an option. Any solutions?

Answer (score 6):

Solved: `sys.stdin.encoding`

Also, for anyone trying `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, it would almost never work and would always be `ascii` according to https://wiki.python.org/moin/DefaultEncoding:

> Its value should be 'ascii' and it is used when converting byte strings to unicode strings.

and

> If you put non-ascii characters into byte string then .decode(sys.getdefaultencoding()) method will fail with UnicodeDecodeError, therefore byte strings should not contain non-ascii characters.

Answer (score 3):

Can't comment to the answer above due to reputation, but:

Be careful with `sys.[stdin|stdout].encoding` when running in non-tty mode:

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/2
$ python2 -c'import locale, sys; print(sys.stdout, type(sys.stdout), sys.stdin.encoding, locale.getpreferredencoding())'
(<open file '<stdout>', mode 'w' at 0x7fa77abff150>, <type 'file'>, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8')

$ ssh $HOSTNAME tty
not a tty
$ ssh $HOSTNAME "python2 -c'import locale, sys; print(sys.stdout, type(sys.stdout), sys.stdin.encoding, locale.getpreferredencoding())'"
(<open file '<stdout>', mode 'w' at 0x7f7991c43150>, <type 'file'>, None, 'UTF-8')
```

As you can see it might be safer to use `locale.getpreferredencoding()`.

(Not a problem on Py3 so this is just for historical record as of 2020 ;-)).

Comment: Well, there are still people who use python2 in 2022, so this is actually useful ; )